# no such module 'PerfectLib'

Tags: linux, swift, rest, module, perfect

I am trying to create a REST service and I am watching this tutorial:
 `https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/77-server-side-swift-with-perfect/lessons/1`
for the Perfect framework and I am stuck because (moment in the tutorial video time~2:31) when I compile this code it says that the PerfectLib module does not exist, even though I have followed every step in the video and downloaded all files the video told me to. I am working on Linux.

Comment: Mostly, cleaning the code, exit xCode and restart xCode will fix the problem for me. I got this alot of times when importing new pods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I said I am a Linux user(Ubuntu) and I do not have Xcode as there is no Xcode for Linux so I can not restart it. I am using Visual Studio as my IDE and compile with REPL (at least I think so, I am a newbie to both Swift and programming in general).

Comment: Ok :( well I am using a Virtual Machine which runs a mac version :). I can not help you out here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Package.swift looks like this:

```
dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 2)
]
```

Comment: so this worked for me, but the interesting part is that this line was almost equal except the "majorVersion" was 3 not 2, i've changed it to 2 it doesn't complain anymore. and despite the complain the project compile and runs fine. any idea why this happens? i had almost the same issues using Vapor with Xcode 9.0

Comment: Please note that the answer is only working for Swift 3.1.
If applying to Swift 4.0, then it comes with:
    .package(url: "...", from: "3.0.0")
And another dependency needs to add in the `target` section as well.

Comment: Also if someone has a lot of dependencies and this happens, try to move this (HTTPServer) line to the top of the array before the other ones so that it is index 0.